# ObservableCollection does not raise CollectionChnaged

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, observablecollection

I looked up a couple of implementations of `ObservableCollection` and here is what I ended up with. I got the event for ADD firing up when starting the service, but when I do a call and update a property of an object in the list the collection does not notify or trigger at all.

`ObservableCollection` handler.

```
public class iGamingObservableCollection 
{
    ObservableCollection<GameInstance> _contentList;
    public iGamingObservableCollection()
    {
        _contentList = new ObservableCollection<GameInstance>();
        _contentList.CollectionChanged += ContentCollectionChanged;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<GameInstance> ContentList
    {
        get { return _contentList; }
    }

    public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (GameInstance item in e.OldItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("removed: State is now: " + item.InstanceState);
                //Removed items

            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (GameInstance item in e.NewItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("added: State is now: " + item.InstanceState);
                //Added items
                //item.PropertyChanged += InstancePropertyChange;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            foreach (GameInstance item in e.NewItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("changed: State is now: " + item.InstanceState);
                //Changed items

                //item.PropertyChanged += InstancePropertyChange;

            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            foreach (GameInstance item in e.OldItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("changed: State is now: " + item.InstanceState);
                //Changed items

                //item.PropertyChanged += InstancePropertyChange;

            }
        }
    }
```

`ObservableCollection` controller

```
public class InstanceManagerService : IInstanceManager
{
    //TODO: FIX THAT CLASS.. THIS IS INITIAL IMPLEMENTATION!!!
    IGameInstanceRepository instanceRepository;
    iGamingObservableCollection notifyList = new iGamingObservableCollection();
    //private Timer updateNotifierTimer;
    public InstanceManagerService(IGameInstanceRepository instanceRepository)
    {
        this.instanceRepository = instanceRepository;
        populateNotifyList();
        //updateNotifierTimer = new Timer((e) => { populateNotifyList(); }, null, 120 , (int)(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds));
    }

    private void populateNotifyList()
    {
        var list = instanceRepository.getInstances();

        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            notifyList.ContentList.Clear();
            notifyList.ContentList.Add(l);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Notify list content updated.");
    }

public bool releaseInstance(Guid instanceId)
    {
        if (instanceRepository.UpdateGameInstanceToFree(instanceId))
        {
            var notifyTask = notifyList.ContentList.Where(g => g.Id == instanceId).FirstOrDefault();
            notifyTask.InstanceState = InstanceState.Free;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but when I do a call and update a property of an object in the list the collection does not notify or trigger at all.

`ObservableCollection` does not work this way. It's `CollectionChanged` fires when an object is added/removed in its collection. That's why `NotifyCollectionChangedAction` does not have `Updated` value. To do what you want, implement `INotififyPropertyChanged` in the class.

Comment: which I had before, but somehow it stopped working and I ended up with this. I will try to revert back with the model implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.